# AWS CodeBuild script fails s3 sync with AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using CodeBuild with

- Image: aws/codebuild/nodejs:7.0.0
- service role: code-buid-some-service-role

In my buildspec the following command runs

```
aws s3 sync ./webroot s3://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-amazing-s3-bucket/test
```

This is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1502332584348",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1502332580996",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/service-role/code-buid-some-service-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-amazing-s3-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-amazing-s3-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Code build is failing with this:

```
[Container] 2017/08/10 02:41:16 Running command aws s3 sync ./webroot s3://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-amazing-s3-bucket/test
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

What am I missing? I have the bucket policy wide open while testing this and it's still failing.

Comment: I wonder if the role / user the service is running under needs a policy to give it permission. It shouldn't, but but maybe it's worth trying.

Comment: @Tim which sort of policy?

Comment: Much like the one you already have, but attached to the role that runs whatever is doing that upload. Have a look at the policy I posted on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/867642/how-to-start-and-stop-aws-ec2-instance-based-on-a-time-based-schedule/867643#867643), you'd just need the S3 parts - the second allow but grant s3:* like you did above.

Comment: I would move away from a bucket policy and just add the permissions to the  to IAM Role instead. I've not seen a role as the principal in a bucket policy. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following to the CodeBuild generated role worked for me:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket/*"
    ],
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and tried everything in this thread. I was trying to do

```
aws s3 sync ./build s3://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-amazing-s3-bucket
```

from a Codebuild action, but the S3 response was always

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

even when I did it from the aws-cli on my laptop (with admin access keys).

It took me several hours to realize that the actual s3 url is supposed to be written like this:

```
s3://some-amazing-s3-bucket
```

instead of

```
s3://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-amazing-s3-bucket
```

That being said, a policy like tedsmitt's has to be attached to the (in my case) codebuild role too.

Hope this helps someone.