# Scheduling EC2 Instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I have an EC2 instance that I use rarely, so it spends a lot of time in a `stopped` state. Because it's using an elastic IP, I want to schedule a very brief `start` and `stop` command once an hour, to avoid incurring extra charges for having an unallocated elastic IP address.

I wanted to try using CloudWatch to schedule the event, but there's no option to `start` an instance on alarm, only `stop` and `reboot` etc. Do I have to make a whole new CloudFormation stack just to do this one task?

Answer (score 3):

A quick calculations show an EIP costs $3.60/month, a M5.Large turned on for one minute an hour costs $1.35 per month. How much effort are you prepared to go to to save a couple of dollars? The most you could possibly save is $3.60 per month, which isn't really worth much time IMHO.

Though saying that, I did change my t2.nano to a reserved instance to save $3/month, but that was very low effort.

The answer to your technical query is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/867642/how-to-start-and-stop-aws-ec2-instance-based-on-a-time-based-schedule). Use the [instance scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/).